# Add button in TinyMCE editor to insert text

Tags: wp-admin, tinymce, visual-editor

I'm searching a way to add a custom button to the TinyMCE editor when clicked insert into the visual editor some text.

For example: button called "Hi" when clicked insert into the editor `"Hello I'm <B>Mark</b>!"`

Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 5):

**Add this to your plugin file or in `functions.php` file in the theme directory**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_141344_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_141344_add_mce_button' );

function wpse_141344_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse_141344-tinymce-scipt', 'url/to/your/custom-tinymce.js' );
}

function wpse_141344_add_mce_button() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'wpse_141344_add_tinymce_plugin' );
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'wpse_141344_register_mce_button' );
}

function wpse_141344_add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['wpse_141344_tinymce_button'] = 'url/to/your/custom-tinymce.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

function wpse_141344_register_mce_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'wpse_141344_tinymce_button' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

**And this is your `custom-tinymce.js` file**

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpse_141344_tinymce_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'wpse_141344_tinymce_button', {
            // image : 'url/to/an/icon', // optional
            text : 'Hi',
            title : 'Hi',
            onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent('Hello I\'m <B>Mark</b>!');
            }

        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: +1 for `editor.insertContent(...)`. I was trying with `ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', '[live-chat-button]');` which was not working and I was getting a bunch of console errors. `ed.insertContent('[live-chat-button]');` worked for me and placed the shortcode in editor. On the page I can also see the actual content of my shortcode :) Wish I could find this before I posted my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105383/cannot-place-shortcode-value-using-editor-button-getting-uncaught-type-error!

Comment: I have answered to your question. Please accept my answer, as it helped you :) @SubrataSarkar

Comment: I don't find a way to "accept". I can only upvote, which I did already for you previous post.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to make a button from scratch try using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your installation path>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "mybutton",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            type: 'menubutton',
            text: 'My button',
            icon: false,
            menu: [
                {text: 'Hi', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('Hello I am <B>Mark</b>');}},
                {text: 'Insert text item 2', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('It is a beautiful day');}}
            ]
        });
    }
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

This [snippet plugin](https://github.com/electricg/tinymce-snippet-plugin)  (electricg/tinymce-snippet-plugin) might be useful if you just quickly want to add custom buttons with drop downs without coding so much.

You can also look inside the plugin to make a high level system if you are interested.

Comment: Answers should be more than links. Please file an [edit] and add all relevant detail inside your answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: I thought recommending a plugin that can help would be useful... Why does that get negative points?

Comment: Please read [answer]. Pay attention to the section *Provide context for links* :-)

Comment: Okay. I just added an explanation of why I posted a link. ^^

Comment: Looks better. Always good to post a short description of what a plugin does and how it works. Removed my downvote. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it's my first time ever using this site.

Comment: Then you should take your time and read through the [help] section. That will help you a lot in future. And as I stated in another comment, never let downvotes break you, they are just an indication how useful others find your post. Downvotes gives you the opportunity to rectify or better a post, and most importantly, downvotes **can** be removed with proper editing.

Comment: Can I delete my post and start again to remove negative points?

Comment: I just added a working sample of code. Hopefully that gets rid of the negative points here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Add this code to `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'droid_buttons' );
function droid_buttons() {
    add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", "droid_add_buttons" );
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'droid_register_buttons' );
}

function droid_add_buttons( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['droid'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/text-button.js';
    echo get_template_directory_uri();
    return $plugin_array;
}

function droid_register_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'droid_title'); // droid_title
    return $buttons;
}
```

Create `.js` file and replace you path/location of js file in below code:

```
    (function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Droid', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
    ed.addButton('droid_title', {
    title : 'Droid Title',
    cmd : 'droid_title',
    image : ''
    });

    ed.addCommand('droid_title', function() {
    var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
    var return_text = "";
    return_text = '<span class="droid_title">Hello I\'m <B>Mark</b>!</span>'; 
    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
    });

    },

    });

    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'droid', tinymce.plugins.Droid );
})();
```