# How to add custom button in wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor

Sometimes I have to write some handy code.ie:

```
 <div class="row w-100">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      Actual Content
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Actual Content2
   </div>
 </div>
```

Is there any way to insert html structure. Let me explain, suppose I click an icon on wp_editor and two box will be added with the above structure and I write *Actual content* on first box and *Actual content2* on second box. That's it. I don't want to use page builder plugin because it adds additional css stuff which decrease performance. Any plugin which serve this purpose exactly the same way is perfect. Any suggestion? Thanks for your time.

N.B: I spent huge time and no luck. I am apologizing if this question is not standard to ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add button in TinyMCE editor to insert text](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141344/add-button-in-tinymce-editor-to-insert-text)

Comment: look here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139163/add-custom-tinymce-4-button-usable-since-wordpress-3-9-beta1

Comment: This sounds like the column block in gutenberg